# Open Superdrive mini-menu - where's this from?

Tags: keyboard, optical-drive

Mac Pro 5,1 with built-in Superdrive. macOS Mojave.

After several reboots where I was changing 'Displays have separate Spaces' - ie nothing at all relevant to the Superdrive - this extra menu item appeared in the right side of the menu bar.

[image]

I've never seen it before. I assume it's from some 3rd party utility but I can't think what. I doubt it's an Apple system utility, as it seems to have [visually] hijacked F12, rather than the default Eject button. [I say visually, because all it does is beep when I actually press F12, it doesn't actually function as Eject. The real Eject key still works.] Selecting Open Superdrive from the menu item itself does open the drawer.

Has anyone any idea what this might belong to, or how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the Eject menulet, which is found here:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Eject.menu
```

You should be able to get rid of it in the usual way, by holding down <kbd>Command</kbd> while dragging it off.

IIRC, <kbd>F12</kbd> was a substitute for open/close on keyboards that didn't have a dedicate eject button.

Comment: So it was [confirmed by throwing it off the menu then re-launching]. No clue what decided it to activate.